# Error message - why does it say "object not found"?

Tags: r, syntax-error

I'm very new to R and stackoverflow, so I apologize ahead of time if I'm breaking any etiquette somehow.

I have only typed a few lines of code so far, following a book tutorial. The book is Statistical Modeling: A Fresh Approach, printed in 2012, so I'm not sure what  version of R it has. I am using R 4.0.0.

All I have written so far is:

```r
cherryBlossom2008 <- read.csv("Cherry-Blossom-2008.csv")
names(cherryBlossom2008)
```

this produces:

```r
[1] "position" "division" "total" "name" "age" "place" "net" "gun" "sex"
```

Next I typed:

```r
mean(age, data=cherryBlossom2008)
```

I immediately get an error message that says:

```r
Error in mean(age, data = cherryBlossom2008) : object 'age' not found
```

I'm not sure how this is possible. 'age' is in cherryBlossom2008. My book says that I would get that error message if I failed to define "data" when using the "mean" command, but as you can see I *did* define "data", so I don't understand how else I would define 'age'.

Comment: the `mean` function does not behave like tidyverse functions, and furthermore it does not ahve a data argument. Try: `with(cherryBlossom2008, mean(age) )`

Comment: or just `mean(cherryBlossom2008$age)`, what may be considered the "normal R way" (`dplyr`, `data.table`, and `with`/`attach` notwithstanding).

Comment: Are you saying that the syntax of ```command(variable, data=filename)``` is specific to tidyverse functions? I just want to be sure I understand!

Comment: Many of the tidyverse functions, yes. Not all.

Comment: seems like my mistake was not installing the "mosaic" package beforehand, which alters the way "mean" works. thank you all for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't referred the book so I may be loosing some context here but based on your explanation and description I think there are few possibilities here.

1. Book is wrong and this is some kind of mistake.

`mean` is an internal command. You can look at the documentation (`?mean`) and notice there is no `data` argument defined in `mean`.

To get `mean` you can use -

```
mean(cherryBlossom2008$age, na.rm = TRUE)
```

2. You are supposed to use `mean` command present in some other library and not base.
3. You have to define your own `mean` function and not use the internal one.

```
mean <- function(col, data) {
  base::mean(data[[deparse(substitute(col))]], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

In which case - `mean(age, data=cherryBlossom2008)` will work.

For eg - with `mtcars` dataset -

```
mean(mpg, data = mtcars)
#[1] 20.09062
```

However, this option is very unlikely.